# close previous layout and inflate another

Tags: android, layout

I have two layouts and I am inflating it one after another ,I want to dismiss previous view and inflate another but the view is shifted to the background ,hence both the dialogs are present.I would like to dismiss the dialog which is in the background.
I have tried following fixes:

1.dialog.dismiss();   --- not working

2.view.setVisibility(View.GONE);   --- Title of the dialog still remains along with dialog.

I am attaching the entire code.Please let me know how to resolve this.Thanks.

menuproject.java

```
        package com.menuproject;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;

        public class menuproject extends Activity {
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */

            AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog2;
            private AlertDialog alert = null;
            private AlertDialog alert2 = null;
            View updatedialog;
            View updatedialog2;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

            }

            protected void layoutsecond() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                this.dialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                this.dialog2.setTitle("Update");

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                updatedialog2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.updatedialog2, null);

                this.dialog2.setView(updatedialog2);
                alert2 = this.dialog2.create();
                this.dialog2.show();

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MenuItem mi = menu.add(1, 1, 1, "My Menu1");
                mi.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));

                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case 1:

                    layoutfirst();

                    Button b = (Button) updatedialog.findViewById(R.id.Button11);
                    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            // updatedialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            // alert.dismiss();

                            layoutsecond();

                        }
                    });

                    break;

                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            private void layoutfirst() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                this.dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                this.dialog.setTitle("Update");
                // this.dialog.setMessage("");

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                updatedialog = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.updatedialog, null);

                this.dialog.setView(updatedialog);
                alert = this.dialog.create();
                this.dialog.show();

            }

        }
```

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

updatedialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView02" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/liner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
            android:text="Update Tel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
            android:text="Update Address" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </View>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

updatedialog2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView021" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
            android:text="Update Mobile" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </View>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried alert.setContentView(inflated_layout) instead dialog.setView(view_name)

Comment: Thanks Bharat for the reply.Above code does not work ,dialog.setContentView() method does not exist.

Comment: I have just checked it was there you are using alertdialog. It is there which api level you are using.

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder dialog; dialog here is AlertDialog.Builder .API level is 8 android 2.2.

Comment: I have changed my answer can you check with your dialog object you can set content view.

Comment: setcontentview will work on alert object not on dialog object in your case. dont setview on dialog object set on alert.setcontentview(layout_name)